# Number before two nouns

Tags: grammar

I was wondering how we use number in front of two nouns, as in:

> There are three  advantages and disadvantages of smoking.

Does it mean three advantages **and also** three  disadvantages as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would take it to mean three advantages and three disadvantages.

Also, when writing a number in a sentence, it should be spelled out: three for the number 3. (I think the rule applies to any number from ten and under). I think I read this in my college English Grammar text book.

Comment: I fully agree on having to spell out _small_ numerals in a sentence lest it reeks of quick messaging over a cell-phone. On "_three advantages and disadvantages_" I'm not sure: to me it would still sound unpleasantly vague and imprecise. As long as I can count them, I'd rather go for "_three advantages and three disadvantages_".

Comment: Texting,  I would use numerals instead of spelling out the number.

Comment: So would I. But R U sure it would look fine? :-)

Answer (score 1):

**It's ambiguous.** It's at least partially a special case of [coordination ambiguity](http://ferreiralab.faculty.ucdavis.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/222/2015/05/Engelhardt-Ferreira-2010_CoordinationAmbiguity_Lang-Speech.pdf): the context-free phrase doesn't precisely specify the scope of the conjunction "and". Is it *(3A) and B*, or *3 (A and B)*? It's also partly about whether (*A and B*) is treated as a unit or whether each is considered separately.

Without context, it can mean any of these:

1. three of each (e.g. [three advantages and disadvantages](https://geektyrant.com/news/2013/1/21/three-advantages-and-disadvantages-the-next-star-wars-series.html));
2. three in total, probably with at least one of each (e.g. [three past and present presidents](http://easthamptonstar.com/Lead-article/2017601/Shalom-Rabbi-Ten-Years)); or
3. three of the first and an unspecified number of the second (e.g. [three pieces of chicken and fries](https://www.ubereats.com/en-US/new-york/food-delivery/kennedy-fried-chicken-&-pizza/bOodruCLToWN1eDZhc9oog/)).

That's before considering constructions such as "one in three cats and dogs ...", which specifies a proportion but leaves the total unspecified.

In the case of *advantages and disadvantages*, #1 is most likely if the speaker is trying to provide a balanced view. However, the other interpretations are not invalid, given appropriate context. The first sentence of this paragraph provides yet another interpretation (a variant of #2) if we take "the case" to imply "one": the conjunction is treated as a single unit.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the previous comments.

Let's look at the following sentence:

There are **both**  advantages and disadvantages  of smoking.

Here **both** emphasizes the fact that **both** advantages and disadvantages exist.

Now let's use the modifier **three**

There are **both three** advantages and disadvantages of smoking.

I think by using the word **both** together with **three** you are providing some **emphasis** to the fact that there are three of each.

Comment: Further to my last comments I also think you could  also write your sentence like this:  There are three advantages and also three disadvantages of smoking.  However,  some might think it too wordy.   hope that helps you.